# Accessing my Model from a background agent in Windows Phone 7 using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a WP7 (Windows Phone 7) project that I am working on which I have used the MVVM approach. I want to now add a background agent to periodically check for new data from a remote server. In my model, I have a method that I need to call from the background agent. The problem is is that I don't have anyway of getting a reference to the model in the background agent. I am using the MVVM light project. Has anyone got any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seperate your model object into a separate project

```
- Project.Model
    ModelClass
    ModelClass2
- Project.Background
    Agent
- Project.Application
    App
    MainPage
```

So in this example, you application and the background projects would reference the model project.